# Efficient way to find mode in a large 2D matrix in python(Scipy)

Tags: python, scipy

I am using **stats.mode()** from **scipy** to calculate mode in a **800*500 matrix**. And the execution time is like:

```
   `Time taken to execute 0.4359015187888584
    Time taken to execute 0.42199154405135975
    Time taken to execute 0.4250416821138656
    Time taken to execute 0.4100701556064723
    Time taken to execute 0.4371956395342953`
```

But I need it under:

```
 Excution time 0.09193338154885265
```

Is there any method to make it efficient?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for your lower bound time requirement?

Comment: yeah!.Actually matrices are sequence of frames in a video.And I have to find modes of those frames before showing the output video. So when I apply that method,output video lags few secs from actual video speed.

Comment: Do you need the row-wise mode or just one mode per frame? Also what data type and  range are your pixels ?

Comment: @PaulPanzer ,Now I am trying to find row wise mode. (one mode per frame  would also be appreciated,but prefer row-wise). Data type I am using is int8 and range is -128 to 127.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why `scipy.stats.mode` is so slow. Anyway, you can get a much faster result using `np.bincount`:

```
# create random frame
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 256, (800, 500)).astype(np.int8)
>>> 
# add row offsets to make bincount create separate bins for each row
>>> counts = np.bincount((a.view(np.uint8) + 256 * np.arange(800)[:, None]).ravel(), minlength=256*800).reshape(800, 256)
# find the mode
>>> values = np.argmax(counts, axis=1)
# discard the counts for all other values
>>> counts = counts[np.arange(800), values]
# convert modes back to original dtype
>>> values = values.astype(np.uint8).view(np.int8)
```

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks a lot @PaulPanzer